# Django Form Code not saving

Tags: django

/deneme.html

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Doktor Ekleme</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dosyalar/base.css" />
</head>
<body>

<h1>Doktor Ekle</h1>

<form action="/deneme/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input maxlength="50" name="adi" type="text" value=""/>
 <input type="submit" value="Gönder" class="default" name="save">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

/views.py

```
from django.http import *
from django.template import RequestContext



  def deneme(request):
if request.method=='POST':
        adi=request.POST.get('adi')
        kaydet=doktor(adi=adi)
        kaydet.save()

    return render_to_response('deneme.html',context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

thats code is not error but not saving

/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class doktor(models.Model):

    adi = models.CharField(max_length='50')

    def __str__(self):
        return 'adi :%s' %(self.adi)
```

not error but not saving

/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import portal_site.views
import yonetim.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'DernekPortali.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'', include('portal_site.urls')),
    url(r'', include('yonetim.urls')),
    url(r'^deneme/',yonetim.views.deneme),

)

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

where is error ? that's code. not save database !! 
help me plsss
help me plsss
help me plsss

that's code not error but code not saving

Comment: Try this: in `urls.py` pass your view method `deneme` as string, not as function:

`url(r'^deneme/','yonetim.views.deneme'),`

Comment: A couple of things : Use django forms instead of plain forms. Second, I dont know how this code is even working - not just the formatting. Even the imports. Third: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Notice the code in views.py, **doktor** should be a class imported from models.py, but I can't find it. I think it's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**dissolved :))))**

/.views.py

```
def deneme(request):
```

replace

```
def xx(request):
```

/.urls.py

```
url(r'^deneme/',yonetim.views.deneme),
```

replace

```
url(r'^deneme/',yonetim.views.xx),
```

that's error => same variable